# Event handling (Detect when hiding form)

Tags: c#, winforms, events, event-handling

Well normally I am quite good at figuring and researching problems without guidance however I have come across a snag. I am trying to create an "Event" with C# (which I have not done before) everything I have looked up has nothing to do with what I need.

I am trying to call a class on my main form when form2 is hidden. I found some code which was supposed to check to see if form2 closed - Either I didn't integrate it into my code properly or closing is different to hiding.

So just to clarify I want to run through the program like this:

- Form1 runs
- Click setting button on Form1 which opens Form2
- Form2 opens where settings can be changed
- Click the "Ok" button on Form2 (here is where I want Form1 to realise Form2 has been hidden
- Hide form one and run a class called Refresh which refreshes button names and URLs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the second form as modal

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
DialogResult result = form2.ShowDialog();
```

check the result and refresh:

```
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    Refresh();
```

What you also need to do in this case is when closing the form set DialogResult of the form, for example if you have an OK button, in the button handler set:

```
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
```

This will automatically close the form as well as I remember correctly.

What you can also do is set DialogResult.Cancel on cancel button if you need that.

Comment: It couldn't find "ShowModal" wanted a reference. I did change it to ShowDialog. It opened fine but when I clicked ok it didn't reference the "Refresh." Where do I place the "result"? I placed it under the "show" on Form1.

Comment: Uh, yes, sorry for the typo, it is ShowDialog()

Comment: Thank you! Been working on events for so long and here you come giving me 3 lines of code. I hate programming sometimes! Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Also, 
you can use `VisibleChanged` event in Form2

```
private Form2_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.Visible) { Refresh(); }
}
```

This might be more elegant...

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to have a class that stores settings information that both Form1 and Form2 can access. Let's call that class `Form1Settings`, and implement as:

```
public static class Form1Settings
{
    public static string ButtonText;
    public static string Uri;
}
```

For simplicity, I made this class and its properties static, so both `Form1` and `Form2` have direct access to it, removing the need for a refresh method.

`Form1` would call `Form2` in a blocking way, and only update its display if the OK button was clicked.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form2 form2 = new Form2();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (form2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.button1.Text = Form1Settings.ButtonText;
            this.textBoxUrl.Text = Form1Settings.Uri;
            this.Update();
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, Form2 will update the settings values with input from the user:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1Settings.ButtonText = this.textBoxButton.Text;
        Form1Settings.Uri = this.textBoxUri.Text;

        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not open Form2 as a modal dialog using `ShowDialog()`? That way you may return a value if Form2 was closed by `OK` or by `Cancel` and act accordingly in Form1 after the call returned.